# Why does babel insert whitespace after parentheses in :var values?

Tags: org-babel

I am running GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2021-03-26 on Windows 10 with org-mode 8.3.4-102-gebe7aa-elpa.  When I #+CALL a code block passing in a var with a parenthesis, a space gets added to the variable value before it arrives at the code block.

This is clearly undesirable, mangling the password in the example below.  My actual babel code is Python but this simple example illustrates the problem perfectly.

```
#+NAME: parenthesis-test
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output
echo $password
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: parenthesis-test(password="y)tk6Q#c$U5")

#+RESULTS:
: y) tk6Q#c$U5
```

Is this expected behaviour?  Is it common or just me? Does anyone know why? How can I prevent this from happening?

Interestingly, the following code block, when run directly gives the correct result:

```
#+NAME: parenthesis-test
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output :var password="y)tk6Q#c$U5"
echo $password
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: parenthesis-test
: y)tk6Q#c$U5
```

So the problem is to do with wrapping the code block in a #+CALL

Edited in response to comments from NickD

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Org mode version 9.4.6 (release_9.4.6-599-gc9dfed). What version are you running?

Comment: Also, what happens if you say `:results output drawer`?

Comment: I am using org-mode 8.3.4-102-gebe7aa-elpa - hadn't realised it was quite that old (it's a very mature org installation).  I guess the advice will be 'upgrade'
WRT drawer: if I run the #CALL the results are identical to berfore.  However if I run the code block directly I get the correct password in the drawer.  Also, if I remove the drawer and call the code block correctly I also get the correct result, so the issue is something to do with the #+CALL (I'll update the question to illustrate)

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce it, it must have been fixed at some point between 8.3.4 and 9.4.6, so yeah: upgrade :-)